# How do I correctly use Firebase's .once() method to store the retrieved value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

EDIT: The following was not my true issue. See answer.

I'm working on a simple html/javascript chat client using Google firebase. The following code is intended to be a rudimentary system of registering and logging in users, wherein the function is provided with an array ($usr) containing a username and password at the [1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002282/firebase-delay-when-retrieving-data) positions.

The local username and password $usr[1-2] are then checked against the database's result (getuser variable, structured as user obj) to determine whether or not a username has already been taken or if the user's credentials are valid. Please note that this is a personal project, the data is not intended to be sensitive.

```js
//Registers user credentials with input [cmd, user, pass]
var auth = function ($usr) {
 var db = firebase.database().ref('chatapp/users/' + $usr[1]);
 var getuser;
 user = {'name': $usr[1], 'pass': $usr[2]};
 db.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  getuser = snapshot.val();
  if ($usr[0] === "/register") {
   if (getuser.name !== $usr[1]) {
    db.set(user);
    notify('Registered ' + $usr[1] + ' with pass "' + $usr[2] + '"');
   } else {
    notify('Username "' + $usr[1] + '" already taken, try again');
   }
  } else if ($usr[0] === "/login") {
   if (getuser.name !== $usr[1] || getuser.pass !== $usr[2]) {
    notify('Invalid credentials ' + $usr[1] + ':' + $usr[2]);
   } else {
    notify($usr[1] + ' logged in');
   }
  }
 });
 
};
```

The issue comes into play at db.once(). The data is being retrieved but is delayed. If a user is attempting to register (getuser.name !== $usr[1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)) will always return True because the variable is set to undefined. However, the login command works flawlessly because by then getuser has been set to the value retrieved from Firebase.

I have tried using .once() only to set the variable, or as a function returning snapshot.val(). I have tried including all of my code within the callback for .once() and using snapshot.val()[name] and [pass] rather than storing it to a variable. The only solution to this seems to be a manual break in the program flow.

In addition, I've also found that using getuser[name] does not work in instances where getuser.name does work, which makes no sense and further infuriates me. Please help, it's 2:12am here.

[Here is the official documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)
[Here is a relevant Stackoverflow question, which may be the solution I'm looking for but I don't understand it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002282/firebase-delay-when-retrieving-data)

What really confounds me is that the function following .then is supposedly reliant on the data being confirmed, which obviously isn't the case.

Comment: Once you have the snapshot, data is not delayed. You store in the variable. You have another problem somewhere, but i couldnt understand your problem very well

Comment: @abeyaz I'm telling you that's not the case. If I put an alert immediately after the snapshot is saved to a variable, it'll return undefined. If I add a second alert later in the flow, it'll return the correct object. getuser.name !== $usr[1] will always return true if the command is /register, but that very same statement in /login returns true or false depending on the value of getuser.name (which is always undefined or null in the first loop.

Comment: Can you please put `console.log(snapshot.val(), getuser)` just after the line `getuser = snapshot.val();`. So, we can see whats going on and produce a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I found a solution that I will be updating with, I think you were correct but there were some quirks to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me:

```js
//Registers user credentials with input [cmd, user, pass]
var auth = function ($usr) {
 var db = firebase.database().ref('chatapp/users/' + $usr[1]);
 var getuser;
 user = {'name': $usr[1], 'pass': $usr[2]};
 db.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  getuser = snapshot.val();
  if ($usr[0] === "/register") {
   if (getuser === null) {
    db.set(user);
    notify('Registered ' + $usr[1] + ' with pass "' + $usr[2] + '"');
   } else {
    notify('Username "' + $usr[1] + '" already taken, try again');
   }
  } else if ($usr[0] === "/login") {
   if (getuser.name !== $usr[1] || getuser.pass !== $usr[2]) {
    notify('Invalid credentials ' + $usr[1] + ':' + $usr[2]);
   } else {
    notify($usr[1] + ' logged in');
   }
  }
 });
};
```

The question was not actually my issue. What led me to believing that retrieval of the data was being delayed is that my code had initially been outside of the `.once()` method's callback function. If you use `.once()`'s callback function to write `snapshot.val()` to a variable, and then write the rest of your code outside of the callback function, the data is written asynchronously and your variable will be set to `undefined` until the true value can be retrieved from the server. I believe that a workaround for this is calling a function with the parameter `snapshot.val()` from within the callback, or simply writing your code within the callback (above).

The actual issue with my code was with the line `if (getuser.name !== $usr[1])`. This causes an error if the value of `getuser` is `null`. The fixed code is above.